# How can I discard an extra line from a contour shape in opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there a way to remove small line segments from a contour?

For example, in this image, the largest contour is a bounding box but we also have a line segment connected to the box.

[image: Contour with an extra line segment]

As contour is a set of Points, I guess we can do something to remove segment of contours that is not part of the box. For example by detecting and removing small lines or small sub contours or another way. But I do not know how I can do it.

Please remember I want to remove them after finding contour and not before that. Do you know how I can remove them? Or any idea?

```
//After edge detection with canny.
//canny variable has the edge mat       
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours( canny, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL,CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );
Mat draw = Mat::zeros(canny.size(), CV_8UC3);

for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++){
    double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if (a>largest_area){
        largest_area = a;
        largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of largest contour
    }
}
drawContours(draw, contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 0, 8, hierarchy);
imshow("Contours", draw);
```

Comment: can you add some reproducible code also? which will be helpful to help you

Comment: @venkatakrishnan I have added the code

Comment: Hi, I have encountered a similar problem, but not exactly the same problem. but what i tried is i computed the min area rectangle (minAreaRect in opencv) and tried reducing the width/height pixel by pixel from sides and computed the area. If the area is still 95% of the overall area, then i delete that particular pixel line. Its more like moving window from width or height. will this be helpful ?

Comment: Yes that may help. I have to find the four corners of the box and its aspect ratio. If you can help with it please post a brief answer. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

In this script, we first make the list of vertices cyclical by appending the first two vertices to the end. For each triplet of vertices, we calculate the distance from the first to the third. If this distance is less than the threshold, we will delete the entire triplet,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def remove_attached_line(vertices, threshold=5):
    if len(vertices) < 3:
        return vertices
    vertices = np.concatenate((vertices, vertices[:2]))

    i = 0
    to_be_deleted = []
    l = len(vertices) - 2

    while i < l:
        distance = np.sqrt(np.sum((vertices[i][0] - vertices[i+2][0]) ** 2))
        print(vertices[i][0], vertices[i+2][0], distance)
        if distance < threshold:
            for k in ((i, (i+1)%l, (i+2)%l)):
                if k not in to_be_deleted:
                    to_be_deleted.append(k)
        i += 1
    vertices = np.delete(vertices, slice(-2, None), 0)
    for i in sorted(to_be_deleted, reverse=True):
        vertices = np.delete(vertices, i, 0)
    return vertices

thresh = cv2.imread(r'Hn9rJ.png')
thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

approxed_countour = []
for contour in contours:
    epsilon = 0.03 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
    approxed_countour.append(approx)
    
approxed_countour = [remove_attached_line(i) for i in approxed_countour]
thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  #add this line

cv2.drawContours(thresh, approxed_countour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]